# Partitions into Parts

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

Is it possible to express $p_m(n)$, the number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of $m$ parts, as some sum involving only $p(\cdot )$? I never seen such a formula before and was wondering whether this is doable. The reason for my interest in this question is that it will give an infinite series expression for $p_m(n)$ by applying the well-known series for $p(\cdot)$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html. I believe there are formulas for $m=2,3,4$. Though the site doesn't provide any sort of proof.

Comment: @user712576 This does not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: Possible? Yes. Useful? Unlikely. If we say that $p_m(n) = \sum_i a_i p(n+i)$ then we can calculate both $p_m$ and $p$ and thus extract the $a_i$, but I wouldn't count on finding any interesting pattern in them.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You say this is possible. Can you do a specific example, for say, $p_5(n)$ and express that entirely in terms of $p(.)$?

Answer (score 0):

Some observations / too long for comments.  I'm not an expert so lemme first confirm the terminology:

- $p_m(n) =$ no. of ways to write $n$ as a sum of $m$ *positive* integers
- $p(n) =$ no. of ways to write $n$ as a sum of any number of *positive* integers
- So we have $p(n) = \sum_{m=1}^n p_m(n)$

First of all, am I correct?

If so, take any $m$-term summation counted in $p_m(n)$, subtract $1$ from every term, and you have a way to write $n-m$ as a sum of $m$ *non-negative* integers, some of which can be zero.  If $m \ge n-m$ then I *think* this is also the number of ways to write $n-m$ as a sum of any number of *positive* integers (since you need at most $n-m$ positive integers and the rest are just padded zeros).  So

> If $2m \ge n$, then $p_m(n) = p(n-m)$

OTOH if $2m < n$ then this trick only counts the number of ways to write $n-m$ as a sum of up to $m$ positive integers, so it is undercounting $p(n-m)$.

> More generally, for any $m,n$ we have $p_m(n) = \sum_{k=1}^m p_k(n-m)$ and the RHS $=p(n-m)$ when $2m \ge n$.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment about this being possible but not useful:

The generating function for $p(n)$ is $$P(x) = \prod_{i\ge 1} (1-x^i)^{-1} = 1 + x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + 5x^4 + 7x^5 + 11x^6 + 15x^7 + 22x^8 + \cdots$$

The generating function for $p_5(n)$ is $$P_5(x) = x^5 + x^6 + 2x^7 + 3x^8 + 5x^9 + 7x^{10} + 10x^{11} + 13x^{12} + 18x^{13} + \cdots$$

Therefore we find that $$P_5(x) = x^5 P(x) - x^{11}P(x) - x^{12}P(x) - x^{13} P(x) + \cdots$$

I haven't double-checked, but I think that what we're doing is extracting the g.f. of $x^5\prod_{i \ge 6}(1-x^i)^{-1}$.